# Why is program w/dynamic linked libraries so large?

Tags: c++, linker, cross-compiling, ld, dynamic-linking

Scenario:
Adding a module to a larger program using `CMake` (cross-compiling for clarity). The larger program statically links all modules and dynamically links some external libraries. I am adding in some functionality, which requires a number of dynamic libraries. I have two questions about this process.

1) Before the titular question, *`ld` is requiring that I link to not only all direct dynamic library dependencies, but also to all recursive dependencies* (dependencies of dependencies, etc). Why is this and can I prevent it? Since dynamic libraries are loaded at runtime, shouldn't I be able to specify that unresolved symbols will be resolved at runtime? I tried adding `-Wl,-unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs` to both compiler and linker flags, but no luck :(. Any suggestions?

1) As stated in the title, when all dynamic libraries are linked (~60 including recursive dependencies), the final executable is REALLY large (relative to before). It goes from **~8MB** to **~72MB**. Also, the linking process takes a REALLY long time (relative to before). Previously it took **~10s**, now it takes **~10min**. Why is the file so much larger?

All answers, links, and comments are greatly appreciated.

Edit
Link command:
`/home/eric/Programs/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.0/gcc-linaro-4.9-2014.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++  --sysroot=/opt/qrlSDK/sysroots/eagle8074  -g -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++11 -fno-threadsafe-statics -DCONFIG_WCHAR_BUILTIN -D__CUSTOM_FILE_IO__ -fcheck-new -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wdisabled-optimization -Werror -Wextra -Wfatal-errors -Wfloat-equal -Wformat-security -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wunknown-pragmas -Wunused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wformat=1 -Wdouble-promotion -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wreorder -fvisibility=hidden -include visibility.h -pthread --sysroot=/opt/qrlSDK/sysroots/eagle8074 -fno-strict-aliasing -fomit-frame-pointer -funsafe-math-optimizations -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-strength-reduce -fno-builtin-printf -O2 -g -DNDEBUG  -Wl,-gc-sections -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/qrlSDK/sysroots/eagle8074/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/qrlSDK/sysroots/eagle8074/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/qrlSDK/sysroots/eagle8074/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/qrlSDK/sysroots/eagle8074/lib --sysroot=/opt/qrlSDK/sysroots/eagle8074 src/firmware/posix/CMakeFiles/px4.dir/px4muorb_stub.c.obj src/firmware/posix/CMakeFiles/px4.dir/__/__/platforms/posix/main.cpp.obj src/firmware/posix/CMakeFiles/px4.dir/apps.cpp.obj src/firmware/posix/CMakeFiles/px4.dir/home/eric/Programs/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.0/libs/common/rpcmem/src/rpcmem.c.obj  -o px4 -L/home/eric/Programs/px4/Firmware/build/posix_eagle_default/external/Install/lib -Wl,--start-group msg/libuorb_msgs.a src/drivers/device/libdrivers__device.a src/drivers/blinkm/libdrivers__blinkm.a src/drivers/linux_sbus/libdrivers__linux_sbus.a src/drivers/pwm_out_sim/libdrivers__pwm_out_sim.a src/drivers/rgbled/libdrivers__rgbled.a src/drivers/led/libdrivers__led.a src/drivers/boards/eagle/libdrivers__boards__sitl.a src/drivers/qshell/posix/libdrivers__qshell__posix.a src/systemcmds/param/libsystemcmds__param.a src/systemcmds/led_control/libsystemcmds__led_control.a src/systemcmds/mixer/libsystemcmds__mixer.a src/systemcmds/ver/libsystemcmds__ver.a src/systemcmds/topic_listener/libsystemcmds__topic_listener.a src/modules/mavlink/libmodules__mavlink.a src/modules/mc_pos_control/libmodules__mc_pos_control.a src/modules/mc_att_control/libmodules__mc_att_control.a src/modules/systemlib/param/libmodules__systemlib__param.a src/modules/systemlib/libmodules__systemlib.a src/modules/uORB/libmodules__uORB.a src/modules/muorb/krait/libmodules__muorb__krait.a src/modules/sensors/libmodules__sensors.a src/modules/dataman/libmodules__dataman.a src/modules/sdlog2/libmodules__sdlog2.a src/modules/logger/libmodules__logger.a src/modules/simulator/libmodules__simulator.a src/lib/controllib/liblib__controllib.a src/lib/conversion/liblib__conversion.a src/lib/DriverFramework/framework/liblib__DriverFramework__framework.a src/lib/ecl/liblib__ecl.a src/lib/geo/liblib__geo.a src/lib/geo_lookup/liblib__geo_lookup.a src/lib/led/liblib__led.a src/lib/mathlib/liblib__mathlib.a src/lib/mathlib/math/filter/liblib__mathlib__math__filter.a src/lib/mixer/liblib__mixer.a src/lib/runway_takeoff/liblib__runway_takeoff.a src/lib/tailsitter_recovery/liblib__tailsitter_recovery.a src/lib/terrain_estimation/liblib__terrain_estimation.a src/lib/version/liblib__version.a src/platforms/common/libplatforms__common.a src/platforms/posix/px4_layer/libplatforms__posix__px4_layer.a src/platforms/posix/work_queue/libplatforms__posix__work_queue.a src/modules/elka_nn/libmodules__elka_nn.a src/modules/rovio/libmodules__rovio.a -L/home/eric/Programs/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.0/libs/common/remote/ship/UbuntuARM_Debug -ladsprpc -lpthread -lm -lrt -Wl,--end-group -L/home/eric/Programs/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.0/libs/common/remote/ship/UbuntuARM_Debug -ladsprpc src/lib/DriverFramework/framework/src/libdf_driver_framework.a -Wl,--start-group -shared -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/eric/Programs/Snapdragon/SnapdragonSetup/libs -L/home/eric/Programs/Snapdragon/SnapdragonSetup/libs -latk-1.0 -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lbz2 -lcairo -lcamera -lcgmanager -ldatrie -ldc1394 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lgcrypt -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgpg-error -lgraphite2 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lHalf -lharfbuzz-gobject -lharfbuzz -licudata -licuuc -lIlmImf -ljasper -ljpeg -lnih -lnih-dbus -logg -lorc-0.4 -lpango-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpcre -lpcrecpp -lpcreposix -lpixman-1 -lpng12 -lselinux -lswscale -ltasn1 -lthai -ltiff -ludev -lv4l1 -lv4lconvert -lX11 -lXau -lXi -lxcb -lxcb-dri3 -lxcb-glx -lxcb-present -lxcb-render -lxcb-shape -lxcb-shm -lxcb-sync -lXcomposite -lXcursor -lXdamage -lXdmcp -lXext -lXfixes -lXft -lXinerama -lXrandr -lXrender -lz -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_videostab -lyaml-cpp -lpthread -lm -lrt`

Edit 2:
Adding in the linker options `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs,--allow-shlib-undefined` seems to allow me to omit recursive dependencies. However, program size is still 10x the previous size. The size of the additional program shouldn't be that much larger. I'm going to try building it in a different way to see if maybe it is actually that large. As before: all help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it may be helpful if you could share the command used to link.

Comment: Looks like you're linking with a bunch of static libraries as well.

Comment: True. The modules are static libraries, all linked into the program `px4`